# Saving / reloading images, and deleting older images

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, nsuserdefaults

I'm loading an image file from a web server, and then saving it to nsuserdefaults. the save code is roughly:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(theImage); // theImage is a UIImage
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:imageData forKey:string]; // string is a 3-dig number which identifies image
```

Now, apparently I'm on the wrong foot already, since images are not recommended for nsuserdefaults..

But what I want to do is save these images somewhere, so they can be accessed without having to re-download them. Additionally, I would like to delete old images (let's say a day old, or keep only the last 10 downloaded images)? Is there a good technique for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the excellent [ASIHTTPRequest library](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) to download the image in the first place :)

This replaces NSURLConnection and you can specify how to cache the images - you would just re-request the images from the same URL and ASIHTTPRequest would return the cached ones.

Comment: Is there a working example of  ASIHTTPRequest cache-ing images for use in a UITableView?

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to images I recommend saving those to disk, there is the Documents folder in the application's sandbox. You could easily store the name of the file in the userdefaults and use it later to access the file.

If you like to find out if an image is "too old" you can do something like this:

```
int aDayInSeconds = 60 * 60 * 24;

NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:fileName 
                                                                            error:nil];
NSDate *creationDate = [attributes objectForKey:@"NSFileCreationDate"];

if ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:creationDate] > aDayInSeconds) {
    // Delete, reload, whatever you need.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your purpose, there are a number of places you can save the downloaded images:

- If you want to store the file until you delete it, write to the documents directory: `[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]`
- If you want to store the file until you delete it and you might ever use [iTunes file sharing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW10) and don't want these particular files shared, write to the Application Support directory: `[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]`
- If you want to allow the system to delete it if the device is running low on space (and don't care if it is saved when the device is backed up), use the caches directory: `[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]`
- If you're just saving it temporarily while you process it and will delete it right away, use the temporary directory: `NSTemporaryDirectory()`

If you want any retention rules like "keep only 10" or "delete after one day", you'll have to implement that in your code yourself. You could rely on file modification dates (from NSFileManager's `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:`), or keep the filename-to-date mapping in NSUserDefaults or Core Data, or just name the files to include the date.